# Mapbox runtime crash: terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException

Tags: android, exception, runtime-error, mapbox

I've seen similar issues raised on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10188) but they were closed after a new version fixed this issue. I've re raised that as a bug but have yet to get a reply.

This crash happens pretty much always when the fragment that contains the map opens (the fragment contains a viewpager and the mapbox's fragment is hosted within that viewpager.

These are the only implementations I'm using:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.2.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.3.0'
```

And this is the complete map fragment:

```
class ImageMapViewFragment : Fragment(), PermissionsListener {


    private lateinit var sharedViewModelForImage : SharedViewModelImage

    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private lateinit var map: MapboxMap
    private lateinit var permissionsManager: PermissionsManager

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        activity?.let {
            sharedViewModelForImage = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(SharedViewModelImage::class.java)
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Mapbox.getInstance(activity!!.applicationContext, getString(co.getdere.R.string.mapbox_access_token))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(co.getdere.R.layout.fragment_image_map_view, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mapView = view.findViewById(co.getdere.R.id.mapView)


        sharedViewModelForImage.sharedImageObject.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let {image ->
                mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                mapView.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->

                    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.LIGHT) { it ->

                        map = mapboxMap

                        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this.context)) {

                            // Get an instance of the component
                            val locationComponent = mapboxMap.locationComponent

                            mapboxMap.addMarker(
                                MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(LatLng(image.location[0], image.location[1])))


                            val position = CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(LatLng(image.location[0], image.location[1]))
                                .zoom(10.0)
                                .build()

                            mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position))


                            // Activate with options
                            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                    this.context!!,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            ) {
                                locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this.context!!, mapboxMap.style!!)
                            }

                            // Enable to make component visible
                            locationComponent.isLocationComponentEnabled = true

                            // Set the component's render mode
                            locationComponent.renderMode = RenderMode.COMPASS


                        } else {
                            permissionsManager = PermissionsManager(this)
                            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(activity)
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        )
    }



    override fun onExplanationNeeded(permissionsToExplain: MutableList<String>?) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Location needed to use map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapView.onStop()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView.onLowMemory()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ImageMapViewFragment = ImageMapViewFragment()
    }

}
```

Comment: Not an answer, per se, but this looks like it could be related to https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/14127. I'd suggest upgrading to 7.3.0 when it is released, which should be in the next few days. Were you seeing this issue in earlier versions of the SDK?

One other thing worth noting is that the LocationLayer plugin is deprecated - I'd suggest reading https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/location-component/ to learn more about the new LocationComponent class.

Disclaimer: I work at Mapbox.

Comment: @samfader thanks for your response and for the product you guys are building. I have to say that maybe I'm trying to get on board in a problematic time because there are a lot of changes, but for a beginner it is currently really hard to understand how to use MapBox. It feels like documentation is everywhere and not consistent. I'll be reading about how to implement markers for example, then I'll learn that it's deprecated (currently no idea what would be the most direct approach to just place one pin on the map).
I hope it'll be easier to understand soon as I'd really want to use it.